# How to add tooltip for Checkboxlist  for each item in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip, checkboxlist

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckl_EditRole" DataValueField="RoleName" runat="server">
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
public void BindListBoxPermission(int field)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int newOrgID = field;
        string MysqlStatement = "SELECT RoleName from tbl_Role Where RoleID >1 order by RoleID desc";
        MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[0];
        ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, MysqlStatement, param);
        ckl_EditRole.DataSource = ds;
        ckl_EditRole.DataBind();
    }
```

For each item tooltip is different, for admin tooltip is creates user and for users tooltip is creates message. How can I add tooltip for each item inside the check box

Comment: You should actually ask a question in the body.

Comment: Yeah  I have changed my question, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in ckl_EditRole.Items)
    {
        item.Attributes["title"] = GetRoleTooltip(item.Value);
    }
}

private static string GetRoleTooltip(string p)
{
    // here is your code to get appropriate tooltip message depending on role
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToolTip property:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckl_EditRole" DataValueField="RoleName" runat="server" ToolTip="Roles">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Is this what you are asking?

If you want to update the ToolTip for each item then you need to treat them separately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ckl_EditRole.Items.Count; i++)
   ckl_EditRole.Items[i].Attributes["title"] = "custom Tooltip";
```

Comment: For each item tooltip is different, for admin tooltip is creates user and for users tooltip is creates message

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreRender event-- loop over the items (should be ListItems), and you can set an html attribute for title based on the values of the checkbox.

In cases where I want to have alot of control over the checkboxes, I might favor putting a checkbox in a repeater-- but that might not be necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following snippet of code on the page load method:
 chkbox.Items[0].Attributes.Add("Title", "Admin");
 chkbox.ToolTip = "Admin";

chkbox.Items[1].Attributes.Add("Title", "User");
 chkbox.ToolTip = "User";

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, with more features, like making the ListItem look like a linkbutton.

```
    protected void FormatPaskWeeksPerStudentRow(GridViewRow gvRow)
    {
            SqlDataSource sdsTETpastWeeks = (SqlDataSource)gvRow.FindControl("sdsTETpastWeeks");
            sdsTETpastWeeks.SelectParameters["StudentID"].DefaultValue = hfStudentID.Value.ToString();
            if (sdsTETpastWeeks != null)
            {
                CheckBoxList cbl1 = (CheckBoxList)gvRow.FindControl("listWeeksTracking");
                if (cbl1 != null)
                {
                    cbl1.DataBind();

                    foreach (ListItem litem in cbl1.Items)
                    {
                        //disable the checkbox for now
                        litem.Enabled = false;

                        //see if any of the past weeks (excluding this week) needs to be highlighted as a hyperlink to show past comments
                        //get the Tracking value. If set, then mark the checkbox as Selected or Checked
                        DataSourceSelectArguments dss = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
                        DataView dv = sdsTETpastWeeks.Select(dss) as DataView;
                        DataTable dt = dv.ToTable() as DataTable;
                        if (dt != null)
                        {
                            //this loops through ALL the weeks available to the student, for this block
                            //it tries to match it against the current ListItem for the week it's loading and determines if they match
                            //if so then mark the item selected (checked=true) if the value in the sub query says it's true
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (litem.Text == dr.ItemArray[0].ToString() && litem.Text != ddlWeekNo.SelectedItem.Text)
                                {
                                    if ((bool)dr.ItemArray[1])
                                        litem.Selected = true;

                                    //for those that were not ticked in prior weeks, make a ToolTip with the text/comment made in that week and underscore the week number
                                    else
                                    {
                                        litem.Attributes["title"] = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                                        litem.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Blue;font-style:italic;text-decoration:underline;");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

So in effect I am placing a ToolTip that's unique based on the data from the DatSource and I change the appearance of the ListItem to blue underline.