# ASP.NET ListItem Text styling

Tags: asp.net

I  have the following -

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="RBL" TextAlign="Right">

      <asp:ListItem Text= "Individual - This is for user" />

      <asp:ListItem Text="Enterprise - This is for enterprises" />

    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

What I like to do is to underline just *Individual* and *Enterprise*.

I tried something like the following but did not work:

```
    <asp:ListItem Text= <span class="underline"> Individual </span>-....
```

as I got:

```
    Error   71  The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects.
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123757/how-to-add-tooltip-for-checkboxlist-for-each-item-in-asp-net You can use same approach to add class attribute to ListItems depending on value

Comment: for what it's worth underlining text clashes with conventional hyperlinks (which are also underlined), consider bold or italic styling as an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want single quote - '.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .underline { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
   RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="RBL" TextAlign="Right">
    <asp:ListItem Text="<span class='underline'>Individual</span> - This is for user" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="<span class='underline'>Enterprise</span> - This is for enterprises" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your text outside of the Text attribute:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="RBL" TextAlign="Right">
  <asp:ListItem> <span class="underline">Individual</span> - This is for user </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem> <span class="underline">Enterprise</span> - This is for enterprises </asp:ListItem>    
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in the Text value for the ListItems:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="RBL" TextAlign="Right">

  <asp:ListItem Text= "<u>Individual</u> - This is for user" />

  <asp:ListItem Text= "<u>Enterprise</u> - This is for enterprises" />

</asp:RadioButtonList>
```