# Set tooltip of checkbox in asp checkboxfield

Tags: asp.net

How can I set the tooltip of a checkbox that is within an asp checkboxfield? It seems there is no tooltip attribute for the checkboxfield. Is there some other way that I can add it to the checkbox?

```
<asp:CheckBoxField tooltip="Test" DataField="datafield" HeaderText="Header Text" />
```

Attribute 'tooltip' is not a valid attribute of element 'CheckBoxField'

Comment: What do you mean? Checkbox has tooltip `<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="My Check" ToolTip="My Tooltip" />` ? If you mean something else - please post your code/markup

Comment: I edited my question. I am using asp:CheckBoxField. @YuriyGalanter

Comment: Looks like you can't, but you could use a TemplateField

Comment: Or u will have to do it in code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123757/how-to-add-tooltip-for-checkboxlist-for-each-item-in-asp-net